# Two different group tree structure in a crystal report from MySql with C#

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, c#-2.0

The following db having unique fields in all tables are ACCYEAR, BILLNO, BILLDATE.
How to get two different tree structure like the following.

```
database name 'billing'
table name: BillDetails

|**********************
|----------> fields (BILLNO: 1, AccYear: 13-14,  BillDate : 03/04/2013, CUSTNAME_AND_ADDRESS: LEO,ZEON NAGARY)
|       |*********************************************************************************************************
|       |
|       |-------->table name: TransportDetails (record 1)
|       |   |     fields(Bill #     : 1
|       |       |       Acc_Year:    13-14 
|       |       |           Bill Date : 03/04/2013
|       |       |           Transport Sl# : 1
|       |       |           Trailer #     : TXT 4568
|       |       |           Driver #      : DRIVER1)
|   |   |
|       |   |       |---------->table name: Cargo Details: (record 1)
|       |   |       |                      fields(Bill #     : 1
|       |       |       |                      Acc_Year:    13-14
|       |       |       |                      Bill Date : 03/04/2013
|       |   |-------------->|                      Transport Sl# : 1
|       |               |                      CargoSlNo:1
|       |               |                      CargoPkgs: 45 WoodenCrates)
|       |           |
|       |           |---------->table name: Cargo Details: (record 2)
|       |                                   fields(Bill #     : 1
|       |                                       Acc_Year:    13-14
|       |                                       Bill Date : 03/04/2013
|       |                                       Transport Sl# : 1
|       |                                       CargoSlNo:2
|       |                                       CargoPkgs: 20 PLTS)
|   |
|       |-------->table name: TransportDetails (record 2)
|           |     fields(Bill #     : 1
|               |       Acc_Year:    13-14 
|               |           Bill Date : 03/04/2013
|               |           Transport Sl# : 2
|               |           Trailer #     : TXZ 0541
|               |           Driver #      : DRIVER2)
|       |
|           |       |---------->table name: Cargo Details: (record 1)
|           |       |                      fields(Bill #     : 1
|               |       |                      Acc_Year:    13-14
|               |       |                     Bill Date : 03/04/2013
|           |-------------->|                     Transport Sl# : 1
|                       |                     CargoSlNo:1
|                       |                     CargoPkgs: 52 CTNS)
|                   |
|                   |---------->table name: Cargo Details: (record 2)
|                                           fields(Bill #     : 1
|                                               Acc_Year:    13-14
|                                               Bill Date : 03/04/2013
|                                               Transport Sl# : 1
|                                               CargoSlNo:2
|                                               CargoPkgs: 10 BALES)
|
|--------------> table name: DocumentDetails (record 1) :
|       |        Document-details-1:
|       |     
|   |
|   |
|       |---table name: ProductDetails:(record 1)------>| table name: ProductDetails:(record 1)
|       |                   |       |   Name : ccc
|       |                   |       |   Manufacturer: pppp
|       |                   |       |   Price : 45000
|   |                   |   |
|       |                   |   |---->|---TABLENAME:PODETAILS(RECORD 1)
|       |                   |         |---TABLENAME:PODETAILS(RECORD 2)
|       |                   |
|       |                   |
|       |                   |------>| table name: ProductDetails:(record 2)
|       |                           |   Name : GFFGH
|       |                           |   Manufacturer: NUGK
|       |                           |   Price : 1285000
|   |                       |
|       |                       |---->|---TABLENAME:PODETAILS(RECORD 1)
|       |                                     |---TABLENAME:PODETAILS(RECORD 2)
|       |        
|       |   
|       |   
|       |---table name: ProductDetails:(record 2)-------|-------->| table name: ProductDetails:(record 2)
|                                   |         |     Name : ccc
|                               |         |     Manufacturer: pppp
|                               |         |     Price : 840000
|                           |     |
|                               |     |---->|---TABLENAME:PODETAILS(RECORD 1)
|                               |           |---TABLENAME:PODETAILS(RECORD 2)
|                               |
|                               |
|                               |-------->| table name: ProductDetails:(record 2)
|                                         | Name : GFFGH
|                                         | Manufacturer: NUGK
|                                         | Price : 950000
|                                 |
|                                     |---->|---TABLENAME:PODETAILS(RECORD 1)
|                                               |---TABLENAME:PODETAILS(RECORD 2)
|
|
|
|-----------------> PAYMTDETAILS(multi records)
```

Comment: Your formatting is killing my eyes.

Comment: Please make appropriate formatting. else we can not be able to understand what you have done

Comment: I don't really know what's being asked, but my best guess is that you're going to need two different subreports in your report? Unless you're talking about the tree view panel on the report viewer? I'm lost, here.